# ansible copy or template a numbered var file

Tags: templates, ansible

I'm trying to template out a file to remote systems. The file should be called:

```
 app_healthcheck-{{ var }}.sh.
```

Where `{{ var }}` is a numbered value, e.g 01, 02, 03.

Lets say the remote system already has these files:

```
app_healthcheck-01.sh
app_healthcheck-02.sh
app_healthcheck-03.sh
```

I'd like ansible to use the next available number, i.e. 04, when templating out the next file. 
Ansible needs to look at the files present in the destination and chose the next value to use. And chose 01 if its the first file.

Any ideas, how i could achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this sure would be possible with Ansible, I argue that doing this with Ansible tasks just gets too complex. Instead I recommend to write a script in the language you prefer and then simply execute it with the script module. The script detects the next ID and then either:

- echos it, which you then can use in the copy/template task
- directly write the file
- copy a previously written temporary file

A simply bash script doing the first option could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

path=/tmp
name=app_healthcheck

i=1
while : ; do
  j="00${i}"
  j="${j: -2}"
  if [ ! -f $path/$name-$j.sh ]; then
    break
  fi
  let i++
done

echo $j
```

This simply echoes 01, 02, ..., 99 whatever next number is free.

Run it with the script module.

```
- script: myScript.sh
  register: nextNumber
```

Then use the result as `{{ nextNumber.result }}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i was heading in that direction. Any idea why your bash script breaks when i=08? Read something about bash reading anything above 07 as octal.

Comment: Good point, only tested until 3. ;-) In that case `i` should not be modified. Just increment it. I updated the script.